# GetLogicalDrives returning drives that do not actually exist?

Tags: c#, mono, c#-3.0

I recently had a [huge struggle with a disk I/O timeout bug](https://superuser.com/questions/979504/load-dialog-disk-access-slowdown-on-windows-10), which eventually came down to the fact that `System.IO.Directories.GetLogicalDrives()` and `System.Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` were returning drive `A:\`, which did not actually exist.  I understand (to an extent) that floppy controllers are not actually smart enough to know that physical media is not connected, so that gets a pass in my book.

However, I'm still getting a ghostly drive `H:\` that does not actually exist.  Currently my solution is to pass all the drives returned by `GetLogicalDrives()` to `Directory.Exists()` to check them before actually accessing them, but this seems a bit hack-y.

(I unfortunately can't use `DriveInfo` as this is actually within Unity, and Mono for some unknowable reason did not implement `DriveInfo` on the Windows platform in the version that I'm bound to.)

So my question is two-fold:

1. Does anyone have an explanation why Windows would return non-existent drives in a function that is pretty obviously requesting drives that exist?
2. Are there any options besides checking the path or using `DriveInfo` to test if a drive actually exists?

Comment: It is not up to Windows, it just reports what the device driver told it.  The cutthroat competition in the hardware business makes it hard to pay a decent programmer's salary, unfortunately they don't compete on driver quality.  You get what you paid for.